# When running pip freeze in Git Bash - TypeError: 'module' object is not callable

Tags: python, django, heroku, git-bash

[[image: git bash terminal error]]When using Git Bash and running anything with pip:

> pip freeze

I get this error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "c:\program files (x86)\python38-32\lib\runpy.py", line 192, in _run_module_as_main

```
return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
```

File "c:\program files (x86)\python38-32\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
exec(code, run_globals)

File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python38-32\Scripts\pip.exe_*main*_.py", line 9, in

TypeError: 'module' object is not callable

I am coming back to this code to deploy on Heroku. But now getting stuck at this stage, which wasn't happening before...

Comment: The questions doesn't specify the outcome that You wish to obtain. Do You want to create a requirements.txt? I have tested the same scenario on my machine both using VS Code terminal and Git Bash with and without environments activated and it seems to work. There might be something I am missing here.

Comment: I am wanted to check if I have virtualenv and then activate. It returns as non-callable regardless what I do.

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to get into the wrong virtual_env, as it was called something-different_env

The answer: Make sure you are in the virtual_env where all what want becomes callable. Look for the (venv) below all of your commands. This means you are successfully in